# Derivative Calculator using LinkedList C++

Tags: c++, parsing, linked-list

I'm trying to make a derivative calculator (I have to use linked list).

The structure of every node should be as follows:

```
struct node {
    int coefficient;
    string function;
    int power;
    node*fx;
    node*gx;
    node*next;
};
```

**| Coefficient | Function | Power | f(x) | g(x) | next |**

---

Input representation example:

3x^2((3x-3)/(4x-2)) + sin(4x-3)

coefficient*function^power(f(x)/g(x)) + next

---

I tried using RegEx but it's not easy to work with when it comes to nesting expressions since the user might throw an unknown number of functions.

I know that I have to parse the expression somehow, then split everything into a vector and then fill in the nodes but I'm just not able to code that logic since I'm fairly new to C++.

I also tried working with ExprTk but I found it hard to understand and I couldn't find any online tutorials for it except the readme file that comes with it.

If anyone can guide me in the right direction or show me a tutorial that would be great.

Comment: You can split the input by `+` while minding the parenthesis so you only have to deal with a list of `coefficient*function^power(f(x)/g(x))` (don't split up `f(x)` or `g(x)` if they contain a `+`) which means the parsing function or regex no longer has to deal with an arbitrary number of functions but only 1. You can then recursively call your parsing function to fill in `f(x)`, `g(x)` and `next`.

Comment: Thank you! That solves the nesting problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its doable with regexp, but you have to put them in correct order. For example:

3x^2((3x-3)/(4x-2)) + sin(4x-3) -> 3x^2((3x-3)/(4x-2)) + sin(n1) -> 3x^2((3x-3)/n2) + sin(n1) -> 3x^2(n3/n2) + sin(n1) -> ...

and so on with regex like this:

\d+\d -> function = +

\d-\d -> function = -

on each step you create new node in memory and leave it in the string also as "n%nodeNum".

Comment: Thank you! I got the hang of it now.